# Opening loginFrame.java with main.java

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jframe

I have just started learning Java from my Java book, and I have a question that might be stupid because im not thinking of it the right way. So I want to make a loginFrame.java class, and start it with my main.java class.

Here is my loginFrave.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class loginFrame {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        String myTitle = "Login";

        myFrame.setTitle(myTitle);
        myFrame.setSize(600, 800);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

This is my main.java (nothing in it because I'm stuck on how to start my other class using main)

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I have tested, and yes my loginFrame.java works how I want it to work for now, which is open a blank screen.
What would I need to add to my main.java to open the login frame by running `java main.java`? Or is this not possible and I will need to always run `java loginFrame.java` instead?

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) An application should only have a single main() method. So you application displays the LoginFrame. Then when that closes, you create and display your next frame.

Comment: I understand your points, but this still does not answer my question, I'm sorry if I'm being unclear, but what I want is to know how to open the JFrame in my main class.
Thanks For the Help!

Comment: Assuming that both classes are in the same folder/location, then you can simply call your loginFrame main method from your main method using `loginFrame.main(args);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a `public static` method in another class you can use:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loginFrame.main(args);
    }
}
```

Note that the way you call another method/class varies by the type of method you are trying to call (Public vs Private, Static vs Instanced etc). See here for some examples: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-class-in-java/